# How can I get an integer value from NSString in an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios4

```
NSString * str=[zoneDict objectForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"==========string zone::==========%@",str);
// str="(GMT +3:00) Baghdad, Riyadh, Moscow, St. Petersbur";
```

How can I get the 3:00 value from the above string?

Comment: Well I'm guessing you don't really want an integer; you want a sign (+), an integer number of hours (3), and an integer number of minutes (00). Is this correct? Also before you go parsing the string, what is the type of `zoneDict`? Time zone data structures usually provide the offset in some more usable form than just a string, but do you only have a string in `zoneDict`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 NSString *str = @"(GMT -3:00) Baghdad, Riyadh, Moscow, St. Petersbur";
 NSRange endRange = [str rangeOfString:@")"];
 NSString *timeString = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(5, endRange.location-5)];
 NSRange separatorRange = [timeString rangeOfString:@":"];
 NSInteger hourInt = [[timeString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, separatorRange.location)] intValue];
 NSLog(@"Hour:%d",hourInt);
```

Comment: The only thing is that NSInteger isn't actually int ^_^ I think it is actually long.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to extract the time offset from the string, is there any way you could store actual time zone data in your `zoneDict`? For example you could store `NSTimeZone` instances instead.

If all you have is the string, you could use an `NSRegularExpression` object and extract the relevant information using a regular expression instead.

If you could explain further what you're trying to do then there may be an alternative way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `-[NSString componentsSeparatedByString]:`

```
NSString *str = @"(GMT -3:00) Baghdad, Riyadh, Moscow, St. Petersbur";
NSArray *myWords = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@")"];
NSString *temp1 = [myWords objectAtIndex:0];
if ([temp1 rangeOfString:@"-"].location == NSNotFound) {
    NSArray *temp2 = [temp1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];
    NSString *temp3 = [temp2 objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"Your String - %@", temp3);
}
else {
    NSArray *temp2 = [temp1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
    NSString *temp3 = [temp2 objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"Your String - %@", temp3);
}
```

Output:

```
Your String - 3:00
```

Comment: wrong. If the value changes in a +GMT value your code don't work.

Comment: Yeah you are write for that you have to check either - or + in the string.I am solving now

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions is the better option in my view (if you are forced to extract the '3' only). The regular expression string would contain something like "\d?" but don't quote me on that, you'll have to look up the exact string. Perhaps someone on here could provide the exact string.